# How to get one records that sorted by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a table like this:

```
id    product_id   price      date
1       1001        100     2017-05-29
2       1005        101     2017-03-30
3       1001        102     2017-03-30
4       1003        106     2017-06-07
5       1005        106     2017-04-30
```

I want to group by `product_id` and get only one latest product for each `product_id`. I also have a min and max price variable which should be applied to the `price` column.

the result of my query should be:

```
1       1001        100     2017-05-29
4       1003        106     2017-06-07
5       1005        106     2017-04-30
```

Is it possible by `SQL` or I should use application side?

Comment: You want to sort the rows by date and fetch just the last record, but your expected result shows 3 and there's no correlation to them either being sorted ascending or descending. Please make yourself clear.

Comment: sorry, last record`s`.

Comment: How many last records? Do you want to use laravel query builder or eloquent? This is a simple sql query. But you need to explain better.

Comment: my records should be group by `product_id` and I have two values of `$min` and `$max` price that I should use `between ` query.

Comment: last records for every `product_id`? also there is possible same `date`s for same `product_id` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to order results by date, just use `orderBy()`:

```
Model::orderBy('date_column', 'desc')->whereBetween('price', [$min, $max])->groupBy('product_id')->take(3)->get();
```

Or it's shortcuts `latest()` and `oldest()`:

```
Model::latest('date_column')->...
```

Comment: your query maybe return two `ids ` of `product_id`.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian you didn't tell anything about grouping or `between` part. I can see you've added this in your comments, so I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html). First select from your table order by date, then use that to group by `product_id`:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `your_table` t ORDER by date desc) as date_ordered group by product_id ORDER by id
```